# Android - Calendar View

Tags: android

In my CalendarView I have an event to access a screen when you click on a date. When I slide my finger for move to the next month the event is called and  it hinders to see the next month. What can I do?

[image: My Screen]

Answer (score 0):

OnTouchListener to change the activity on swipe(you can check [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) ). You need to create a activity that will contain the calendar of other month.